# Strip lines from text file based on content

Tags: powershell

I like to use one of the packaged HOSTS (MVPS,) files to protect myself from some of the nastier domains.  Unfortunately, sometimes these files are a bit overzealous for me (blocking googleadsservices is a pain sometimes).  I want an easy way to strip certain lines out of these files.  In Linux I use:

```
cat hosts |grep -v <pattern> >hosts.new
```

And the file is rewritten minus the lines referencing the pattern I specified in the `grep`.  So I just set it up to replace `hosts` with `hosts.new` on reboot and I'm done.

Is there an easy way to do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you'd do

```
(Get-Content hosts) -notmatch $pattern | Out-File hosts.new
```

or

```
(cat hosts) -notmatch $pattern > hosts.new
```

for short.

Of course, since `Out-File` (and with it the redirection operator) default to Unicode format, you may actually want to use `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`:

```
(Get-Content hosts) -notmatch $pattern | Set-Content hosts.new
```

or

```
(gc hosts) -notmatch $pattern | sc hosts.new
```

And since the input file is read in a grouping expression (the parentheses around `Get-Content hosts`) you could actually write the output back to the source file:

```
(Get-Content hosts) -notmatch $pattern | Set-Content hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156725/45375) (which offers pragmatic and concise solutions based on reading the entire input file into memory up-front):

PowerShell's `grep` equivalent is the [`Select-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) and, just like `grep`, it directly accepts a filename argument (PSv3+ syntax):

```
Select-String -NotMatch <pattern> hosts | ForEach-Object Line | Set-Content hosts.new
```

- `Select-String -NotMatch <pattern> hosts` is short for
  `Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern <pattern> -LiteralPath hosts` and is the virtual equivalent of
  `grep -v <pattern> hosts`
- However, `Select-String` doesn't output *strings*, it outputs [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instances that *wrap* matching lines (stored in property `.Line`) along with metadata about the match.
- `ForEach-Object Line` extracts just the matching lines (the value of property `.Line`) from these objects.
- `Set-Content hosts.new` writes the matching lines to file `hosts.new`, using "ANSI" encoding in Windows PowerShell - i.e., it uses the legacy code page implied by the active system locale, typically a supranational 8-bit superset of ASCII - and UTF-8 encoding (without BOM) in PowerShell *Core*.
  Use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify a different encoding.

  - `>`, by contrast (an effective alias of the [`Out-File` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)), creates:

    - UTF16-LE ("Unicode") files by default in *Windows PowerShell*.
    - UTF-8 files (without BOM) in PowerShell *Core* - in other words: in PowerShell *Core*, using
      `> hosts.new` in lieu of `| Set-Content hosts.new` will do.
  - Note: While both `>` / `Out-File` and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) are suitable for sending *string* inputs to an output file, they are not generally suitable for sending other data types to a file for *programmatic* processing: `>` / `Out-File` output objects *the way they would print to the console / terminal*, which is pretty format for *display*, whereas `Set-Content` *stringifies* (simply put: calls `.ToString()` on) the input objects, which often results in loss of information.

    - For *non-string data*, consider a (more) structured data format such as XML (`Export-CliXml`), JSON (`ConvertTo-Json`) or CSV (`Export-Csv`).